# peak_widths w.r.t to x axis

Tags: python, scipy

I am using scipy.signal to calculate the width of the different peaks. I have 100 values wrt to different time points. I am using following code to calculate the peak, then width. The problem is it is not considering the time on x axis while calculating the width.

```
peaks_control, _ = find_peaks(x_control, height=2100)
time_control     = time[:100]
width_control    = peak_widths(x_control, peaks_control, rel_height=0.9)
```

The output of width_control is

> array([12.84785714, 13.21299534, 13.4502381 , 12.71311143]),
> array([2042.5, 2048.8, 2057.4, 2065. ]),
> array([ 5.795     ,28.29469697, 51.245     , 74.17150396]),
> array([18.64285714, 41.50769231, 64.6952381 , 86.88461538]))

I am using following to use time on x axis and show the signals, which is correct

```
plt.plot(time_control, x_control)
plt.plot(time_control[peaks_control], x_control[peaks_control], "x")
#plt.plot(np.zeros_like(x_control), "--", color="gray")
#plt.xlim(time_control.tolist())
plt.title('Control')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('RFU')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I am using following code to show the width also, but not able to put the actual time on x axis.

```
plt.plot(x_control)
plt.plot(peaks_control, x_control[peaks_control], "x")
plt.hlines(*width_control[1:], color="C3")

plt.title('Control')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('RFU')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the width of those red lines as a number, or do you mean the x axis ticks are wrong (0 to 100 instead of 0 to 10)?

Comment: I mean both, the ticks are wrong. it should be from 0 to 10. Also, the width is being calculated with the assumption that x axis is from 0 to 100. It should be from 0 to 10.

Comment: The first plot runs 0 to 10.  Your X axis there is `time[:100]`.  Does it have 0 to 10 in steps of 0.1?  For your second plot, you didn't supply an X axis.  If you did `plt.plot(time_control, x_control)` for that plot, I believe it would work.

Comment: thats correct, but width_control[1:] arent wrt to time and they go off the chart

Comment: If you divided width_control by 10, couldn't you use time_control as the x axis?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. I was wondering if you or anyone else found a solution to this and can share it with us? @user1631306

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem just now, so here's my solution (there are probably more elegant solutions but this worked for me):

`peak_widths()` returns the widths (in samples), height at which the widths were calculated, and the interpolated positions of left and right intersection points of a horizontal line at the respective evaluation height (also in samples).

To convert those values from samples back to our x-axis we can use `scipy.interpolate.interp1()`:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def index_to_xdata(xdata, indices):
    "interpolate the values from signal.peak_widths to xdata"
    ind = np.arange(len(xdata))
    f = interp1d(ind,xdata)
    return f(indices)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = np.sin(4*x-0.2)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)
widths, width_heights, left_ips, right_ips = peak_widths(y, peaks)

widths = index_to_xdata(x, widths)
left_ips = index_to_xdata(x, left_ips)
right_ips = index_to_xdata(x, right_ips)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], "x")
plt.hlines(width_heights, left_ips, right_ips, color='r')
plt.xlabel('x values')
plt.ylabel('y values')
plt.show()
```

[image of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z9BG.png)